# What does mean digits after dots?

Tags: networking, routes, mac-address

can you please help me to know what is the **1a** after point mean in the following MAC address? Also why it starts from 01 and after that MAC address starts.

Many thanks!

**01**74.b2ba.c585.**1a**

Answer (score 0):

That is not a hardware address, but rather a client identifier.

Many DHCP clients will use a client identifier to require an IP address.

Most client software construct this by prepending “01” to the hardware address.

In your example, the `0174.b2ba.c585.1a` is `01` and the hardware address `74b2.bac5.851a`.